# Effect of max-width on table-cell's size

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Here is a jsfiddle where you can see cells expanding outside of their container(or extending the size of a table when this happens with tables) because:

1. of a long word even if "word-wrap: break-word" is set
2. of a large div even if "overflow: hidden" is set

http://jsfiddle.net/NUHTk/166/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftBlock">
       Too-much-text-ъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъъ
    </div>
    <div class="rightBlock">
        Right block content
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="leftBlock">
        <div style="width: 1200px; height: 200px;">
            Huge element
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightBlock">
        Right block content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container
{
    width: 500px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background: rgb(255,240,240);
}

.leftBlock, .rightBlock
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.leftBlock
{
    width: 100%;
    //max-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgb(240,255,255);
}

.rightBlock
{
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    background: rgb(200,200,200);
}
```

This issue can be fixed by adding a "max-width: 0" to .leftBlock, result of which can be seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/CyberAP/NUHTk/103/

This same problem and fix can occur when dealing with tables.

This feels like a hack. My questions are:

1. why does max-width: 0 solve the problem.
2. Why and how does it change the behavior of the cell sizing.
3. I guess, why isn't this the default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can add display:table; and table-layout:fixed to container class. Hope this is solve your issue.